# Button placed in FrameLayout does not work properly in 2.3.6 device, even though compiled from 2.3.3 (API 10) SDK

Tags: android

I have installed API Level 10 SDK ( aka 2.3.3 ).

I've made a simple linear arrangement of Buttons added programmatically on FrameLayout.

minTargetVersion = "8"
maxTargetVersion = "10"

Runs properly on ICS 4.0.4 device.
Runs properly on Simulator.
But when I install the apk in devices having OS 2.3.5 or 2.3.6, then the buttons do not obey  the left margin parameters and all comes clubbed one onto another.

I've seen that FrameLayout was introduced in API Level 1, while the running devices are at API level 10 or higher, which shouldn't be a problem.

My sample code of adding a button

```
Button b1 = new Button(this);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainActivityView);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100); //a 100x100 button
params.leftMargin = 10; // in other buttons, this values is incremented as  100, 200
params.topMargin = 10;
frameLayout.addView(b1,params);
```

Can anyone let me know what could be causing such improper behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding gravity to your params.

```
params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
```

I had the same problem and it solved it.